# Did Felix Bloch really discover Bloch oscillations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

A 1929 paper by Felix Bloch, [Über die Quantenmechanik der Elektronen in Kristallgittern](http://www.pwein.at/physics/Lectures/Famous-Papers/Z-Physik-52-555-1928.pdf), is widely cited as having predicted the phenomenon of *Bloch oscillations*: The oscillatory motion of an electron in a periodic potential when a constant force is applied.

**Is this attribution correct?**

The 1929 paper has a section (starting on page 572) where the effect of a uniform electric field on the electrons in a crystal is considered, but I could not find any mention of oscillatory motion in that section or elsewhere in the paper. Did I overlook something?

---

The first explicit mention of periodic motion that I am aware of is in a 1934 paper by Clarence Zener, [A theory of the electrical breakdown of solid dielectrics](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1934.0116):

[image]

Perhaps we should speak of "Zener oscillations" ? I note that the term "Bloch-Zener oscillations" is used in the literature, but that refers to the superposition of Bloch oscillations and Zener tunnelling, not to the oscillations *per se*.

---

I reproduce here the translation the paragraphs in Bloch's 1929 paper that adress the motion of the electrion in a uniform magnetic field (page 572). No mention is made of the oscillatory motion that follows from equation 48.

> $$\frac{d}{dt}|c_{klm}|^2=-\frac{KeF}{h}\frac{\partial}{\partial
>  k}|c_{klm}(0)|^{2},\;^{\ast}\qquad\qquad(48)$$
>
> It can be seen that if initially the amplitudes of the eigenfunctions
> building up our wavepacket are given by (46), this distribution of the
> amplitudes in the $k,l,m$-space shifts towards increasing values of
> $k$, more rapidly the larger the field strength $F$ is. In the limit
> of perfectly free electrons, (48) passes directly into that, what one
> would expect according to classical mechanics. According to (9) then
> the velocity in the $x$-direction is given by
>
> $$v_x=\frac{kh}{mK}$$
>
> and instead of (48) one can write
>
> $$\frac{d}{dt}|c_{klm}|^2=-\frac{eF}{m}\frac{\partial}{\partial
>  v_x}|c_{klm}|^2.$$
>
> This would also be expected classically, when a cloud of electrons
> experiences an acceleration $\frac{eF}{m}$.$^{\ast\ast}$
>
> ---
>
> $^\ast$ Mr. Peierls has kindly pointed out to me that one can derive
> equation (48) also independently of the special form (41) of the wave
> packet. It does seem in any case necessary that the initial stationary
> state is not sharply defined.
> $^{\ast\ast}$ Cf. E.H. Kennard, l.c.

Comment: Isn't this the typical theme of Stigler's law of eponymy? A large number of named effects are not named after the right person.

Comment: Given the original German paper of Felix Bloch http://www.pwein.at/physics/Lectures/Famous-Papers/Z-Physik-52-555-1928.pdf does anyone have or know of an English translation of it? There exists a partial translation https://courses.physics.ucsd.edu/2018/Fall/physics211a/topic/bloch.pdf, though it is nothing compared to the 46 pages original paper.

Comment: @Sha --- I don't know of an english translation of the entire paper, but I have translated the text that addresses the motion in a uniform electric field. There Bloch could very well have noted the oscillatory motion, but he does not.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks. I think reading and analyzing the entire paper would be the best way to reach a definitive conclusion. Unfortunately, I do not know German language. By the way, I think translating and maybe commenting on this paper would be a great research task. I hope to see this accomplished someday.